# Remove elements from the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, that I am trying to combine using concatenate:

```
a = np.array(([1,2], [5,6], [9,10]))
b = np.array(([3,4], [7,8], [11,12], [13,14], [17,18]))
c = np.concatenate((a,b), 1)
```

This wont work because the lengths of the arrays are different.  Therefore I am using len to compare the lengths of the two arrays and then determine the length for c based on the minimum length:

```
alength = len(a)
blength = len(b)
lengthforc = min(alength, blength)
```

In this example the minimum `lengthforc` is 3.  Therefore I am trying an if statement to reduce the length of b by deleting the last two rows(elements).

```
if blength > lengthforc:
   rowstoremove = blength - lengthforc
```

How can I modify this if statement to carry out what I want (as the number of rows to remove will change), unless there is another way?.  The final array should be:

```
>>> print c
  [[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11 12]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hstack`:

```
a = np.array(([1,2], [5,6], [9,10]))
b = np.array(([3,4], [7,8], [11,12], [13,14], [17,18]))
end = min(a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
np.hstack((a[:end], b[:end]))
```

Result:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

**EDIT**

If you don't need NumPy arrays you can go with lists:

```
a_list = [[1,2], [5,6], [9,10]]
b_list = [[3,4], [7,8], [11,12], [13,14], [17,18]]
```

Just one line:

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(a_list, b_list)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got the problem correctly (in my solution I just used lists), 
but is it just that simple ?

```
a = [[1,2], [5,6], [9,10]]
b = [[3,4], [7,8], [11,12], [13,14], [17,18]]
c = []
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    c.append(x+y)
```